# BaseAdapter or ArrayAdaptor - Android

Tags: android

I am going to make a grid of images and I am trying to figure out whether to use an array adaptor or a baseadaptor. While the [GridView example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html), stores the data in an array, it uses a BaseAdapter rather than a ArrayAdaptor. I am curious why this is. One thing I noticed about an ArrayAdapter, is that its constructor takes a `textViewResourceId` for some unknown reason - although the documentation say the getView can be used to make it work with other kinds of views as well. So, if I want a fixed grid of images for a menu, which class would you recommend choosing?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You typically choose your adapter class based on what the model data is. If you have an `ArrayList` of objects, use `ArrayAdapter`. If you have a `Cursor` from a database query, use a `CursorAdapter`. `BaseAdapter` can be used for anything, but it requires more coding, since it has no innate knowledge of how to iterate over the data.

Comment: If I use `ArrayAdaptor`, what do I do with the `textViewResourceId` given that I am using images rather than text?

Comment: @Casebash: Ignore it, override `getView()`, and return what you need.

Comment: But you have to pass something in. Would 0 work okay or would -1 be better?

Comment: @Casebash: I don't think it matters.

Comment: @Actually, that doesn't work. Both cause the program to crash

Comment: @Casebash: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/FancyLists/Recycling/

Comment: @CommonsWare: Wow, that excerpt is very nice! Thanks

Comment: BTW, you were right. It doesn't make a difference - as long as when you override `getView` you don't call the method in the super class

Comment: @Casebash: Ah, yes. For your case, you would not want to chain to the superclass.

Comment: A little late on this, but I've noticed that there are some efficiency issues with very large data sets and ArrayAdapter when applied to a grid view.  Replacing that ArrayAdapter with an extended BaseAdapter fixed an issue I'd had with attempting to display lists of many thousands of images.