# Which Adapter to Use - BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I have a JSON string with the multiple instances of the following

1. Name
2. Message
3. Timestamp
4. Profile photo url

I want to create a ListView where each list will have the above. Which is the better Adapter I need to extend for this particular case, to create a Custom Adapter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349693/baseadapter-or-arrayadaptor-android check this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My assumption is that you have parsed the JSON string into an object model prior to considering either case... let's call this class Profile.

**Strategy 1**

An ArrayAdapter is sufficient with an overriden getView(..) method that will concatenate your multiple fields together in the way you wish.

```
ArrayAdapter<Profile> profileAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Profile>(context, resource, profiles) {
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View v;
      // use the ViewHolder pattern here to get a reference to v, then populate 
      // its individual fields however you wish... v may be a composite view in this case
   }
}
```

I strongly recommend the ViewHolder pattern for potentially large lists:
https://web.archive.org/web/20110819152518/http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7767

It makes an enormous difference.

- *Advantage 1.* Allows you to apply a complex layout to each item on the ListView.
- *Advantage 2.* Does not require you to manipulate toString() to match your intended display (after all, keeping model and view logic separate is never a bad design practice).

**Strategy 2**

Alternatively, if the toString() method on your representative class already has a format that is acceptable for display you can use ArrayAdapter without overriding getView().

This strategy is simpler, but forces you to smash everything into one string for display.

```
ArrayAdapter<Profile> profileAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Profile>(context, resource, profiles)
```

Comment: Overriding BaseAdapter in this case adds additional complexity with no real advantage.  You will have to implement getCount(), getItemId(), getItem(..), etc and will find that your implementations are fairly boilerplate.

Comment: @jkschneider - perfect answer. Exactly the reasoning i needed to use the array adapter